# Is 'eat slugs' an actual incantation?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

In CoS, Ron famously casts the spell to Malfoy saying 'eat slugs', but it backfires and he ends up on the receiving end of it from his faulty wand.  It got me wondering - is 'eat slugs' an actual incantation, or was Ron using a non-verbal spell at the time (possible because he was so angry perhaps), or was it something else I'm not considering?

Comment: Movie based or Book based?

Comment: I think it has the incantation “Slugulus erecto”, or something similar, but I can’t check right now.

Comment: @alexwlchan - It's named in the lego game but not in the film or the book

Comment: @Richard: Ah yes, that’s it. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Seems more like a "Vomit Slugs" charm, unless I've been eating wrong all these years...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is. In the book "Order of the Phoenix", it states that the [slug-vomiting charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Slug-vomiting_Charm) is a recognised spell.

> *"Harry was reminded forcibly of the time that Ron had accidentally put a **Slug-Vomiting Charm** on himself."*

In the film, Ron shouts "eat slugs" whereas in the book, he simply casts it nonverbally.

> A loud bang echoed around the stadium and a jet of green light shot
>   out of the wrong end of Ron's wand, hitting him in the stomach and
>   sending him reeling backwards on to the grass

Moving down the canon order, the spell is explicitly named in Lego Harry Potter Years 1-4. You can buy the [Slugulus Eructo](http://legohpotter.wikia.com/wiki/Slugulus_Eructo) charm from Wiseacre's Spells.

Comment: I always wondered why on earth vomiting slugs would be considered a "charm". Charms seemed like useful or beneficial spells - cleaning, mending, conjuring water or flowers... not quite sure where vomiting slugs fits in this. That's definitely a hex or a curse in my book.

Comment: @anaximander - The difference between a charm,  a hex and a spell in Harry Potter seem extremely unclear.

Comment: Maybe they were charming and polite slugs.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - According to the wiki, they came in a variety of delicious flavours...